# Extracting modulus from kSecAttrApplicationTag in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, security, openssl, public-key-encryption

I'm trying to extract a modulus from `kSecAttrApplicationTag` (where I get the public key information from a URL). I'd like to compare the public key which comes from server and the manual input. If both are the same, then we will allow the user to proceed. Otherwise, it will cancel the user's request. 
This is the piece of code:

```
SecTrustRef trust = [protectionSpace serverTrust];
SecKeyRef publicKey = SecTrustCopyPublicKey(trust); // here i'm getting complete SecKeyRef info
NSMutableDictionary * queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)publicKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
```

I tried getting the modulus using `kSecAttrApplicationTag` and `publickey` also but no luck.

Output for `kSecAttrApplicationTag` key is:

```
{
atag = "<SecKeyRef algorithm id: 1, key type: RSAPublicKey, version: 2, block size: 2048 bits, exponent: {hex: 10001, decimal: 65537}, modulus: 98A8819BAEA1361029F78D1FA35B4A39A9C6D017501BD56C8D656CAC0800DE90BCF93D465CC7CAFB697841B3DCF47CE4F35E00CC3CC163, addr: 0xa065400>";}
```

Output  for publicKey is the same as `kSecAttrApplicationTag`  but without `{atag =}` (it has the rest of the content).

Can some one help me with the solution how to extract the modulus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `atag` is XML so there are a few of ways.

1. Use an XML parser: `NSXMLParser`.
2. Use a regular expression: `NSString` method `rangeOfString:options:` with the option `NSRegularExpressionSearch`.
3. Use `NSScanner`.

Using a regular expression:

```
NSString *atag = @"<SecKeyRef algorithm id: 1, key type: RSAPublicKey, version: 2, block size: 2048 bits, exponent: {hex: 10001, decimal: 65537}, modulus: 98A8819BAEA1361029F78D1FA35B4A39A9C6D017501BD56C8D656CAC0800DE90BCF93D465CC7CAFB697841B3DCF47CE4F35E00CC3CC163, addr: 0xa065400>";

    NSRange range;

    NSString *blockSizeRegex = @"(?<=block size:\\s?)[0-9]+";
    range = [atag rangeOfString:blockSizeRegex options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSString *blockSize = [atag substringWithRange:range];
        NSLog(@"blockSize: %@", blockSize);
    }

    NSString *modulusRegex = @"(?<=modulus:\\s?)[0-9A-Z]+";
    range = [atag rangeOfString:modulusRegex options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSString *modulus = [atag substringWithRange:range];
        NSLog(@"modulus: %@", modulus);
    }

    NSString *exponentRegex = @"(?<=decimal:\\s?)[0-9]+";
    range = [atag rangeOfString:exponentRegex options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSString *exponent = [atag substringWithRange:range];
        NSLog(@"exponent: %@", exponent);
    }
```

Output:

> blockSize: 2048
>   modulus: 98A8819BAEA1361029F78D1FA35B4A39A9C6D017501BD56C8D656CAC0800DE90BCF93D465CC7CAFB697841B3DCF47CE4F35E00CC3CC163
>   exponent: 65537

ICU User Guide [Regular Expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)

Comment: Tnx for the help, but it didn't work app is crashing when we check range of string. because <SecKeyRef....> is an object here.

Comment: Did this extract the modulus for you, that was the question. If not what went wrong, post the code that failed.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType rangeOfString:options:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa85e200'  in this line of code "NSRange range = [atag rangeOfString:regex options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
"

Comment: What was atag? Did you println it? What type is it, it needs to be a `NSString`. My *example* code expects a `NSString`. Notice that the answer code does run without exception.

Comment: input i'm providing is     NSString *atag = (NSString *)[queryPublicKey objectForKey:@"atag"]; , atag has classname =_NSCFType

Comment: worked when i used [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[queryPublicKey objectForKey:@"atag"]] as input , tnx

Comment: Which is the same as: `[queryPublicKey objectForKey:@"atag"]`, stringWithFormat is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code stores the value of atag key as a SecKeyRef, which does not respond to NSString methods (it is a CFTypeRef).

Consider using:

```
NSString* publicKeyDescription = (NSString*)CFCopyDescription(publicKey);
```

CFStringRef and NSString are tollfree bridged (you will have to cast the correct bridge cast).

Then with that NSString in hand, you should be able to use the provided answer code to find the modulus inside the string.